# How to set uglifyjs options in webpack cli?

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs, webpack-4

I'm using webpack 4 over the cli with the following command:

```
webpack main.js -o public/main.js --module-bind js=babel-loader -p --display-modules --sort-modules-by size
```

How can I tell webpack the uglifyjs config over **CLI** (without a config file) to remove all comments also header comments of scripts?

Comment: you cannot do that using CLI, you'll have to write a config file.

Answer (score 0):

u can try to do it in webpack.config.js:

```
...
 output: {
        comments: false,
        beautify: false,
        ...options
      },
...
```

Comment: thx for your response but as said I search for a **CLI** solution so without webpack.config.js